# Do programs become heavy due to extra empty lines?

Tags: vb.net, performance

I'm making a program in VB.Net and I was wondering that if we keep extra lines in between code, will the program become heavy or even slightly heavy?

Comment: I don't think it will matter for the compiled binaries. The source code (text) file size will increase however.

Comment: You can't weight a program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about complexity and time consumption they don't add anything, since the compiler (or the interpreter) just skips them. If you are talking about how much space they take on the disk it depends.

In *compiled* programs (languages such as C, VB.net) you normally release the executable, and the compiler that produces it strips all the blank lines, whitespaces and tabs.

In *interpreted* programs (languages such as python) you normally release the script itself, so every character adds up to the total size. But it is just 1 byte for every one of them (two bytes for newline in windows) so you shouldn't care, you should make your code comprehensible and well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Empty lines, as well as commented ones are skipped by the compiler so won't affect your performances.